# What is proper meaning of HAR and HARI

Tags: vishnu, shiva

I believe that Shiv has called `HAR` and vishnu named `HARI`.

What is meaning of **HAR** and **HARI**

Comment: also one more i hear that HARIHAR combination of HARI and HAR

Comment: [Meaning of Hara.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17334/what-is-the-meaning-of-hara/17337#17337)

Comment: @K.C.Polai yes i also hear that 'HAR' is combination of Shiv+Narayan is it true

Comment: I have not heard that @azinkey, when you hear it you might know true or false

Comment: Partial duplicate of [What is proper meaning of HAR and HARI](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17334/3500)